# Android, Get GPS location when clicking a button

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to learn how to use GPS service in Android and for that, I am developing a program that show the actual gps location when the user press a button.

But whenever I press it, I get a 0.0...

I think this is the piece of code that is not working fine:

```
LocationManager mlocManager=null;
    LocationListener mlocListener;
    mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,"onCLickButton");
                firstCoord.setText("");
            Log.d(LOGTAG,Double.toString(MyLocationListener.latitude));
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "AAAAAAAA");
            if(MyLocationListener.latitude>0)
                {
                    coordLat1 = MyLocationListener.latitude;
                    coordLon1 = MyLocationListener.longitude;
                    firstCoord.setText(Double.toString(coordLat1) + ' ' + Double.toString(coordLon1));
                }
                else
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(home_screen.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Wait");
                    alert.setMessage("GPS en progress, wait.");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    alert.show();
                }
        }
    });
```

The first log after onClickbutton, shows 0.0 but If I use google maps app, it shows my mobile phone where it is. So problem I think is I am not getting coordinates.

This is my MyLocationListener class:
    package com.gps.distance;

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

private static final String LOGTAG = "LogsAndroid";
public static double latitude;
public static double longitude;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    latitude=loc.getLatitude();
    longitude=loc.getLongitude();
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "TAKE POS");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
{
    //print "Currently GPS is Disabled";
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "GPS DISABLED");
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
{
    //print "GPS got Enabled";
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "GPS ENABLED");
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
{
}
}
```

onLocationChanged is never used. If I Disable or enable GPS, logs appear but onLocationChanged not... Never.

Comment: Have you enabled the ontext.LOCATION_SERVICE in your XML?

Comment: I have enabled ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: You have to go outdoors.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't show anything. With logs, I just can see that latitude and longitude is 0.0

Comment: Are you working with a real devive or are you using the emulator? If emulator, did you grant ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION?

Comment: Have you tried passing a pseudo latlong into the emulator as well if ure using an emulator?

Comment: remove static for latitude,longitutde and check